# Install 64 bit Pythonxy 2.7

Tags: python

I don't succeed in installing **pythonxy 2.7** in a **64 bits** environment. 
After downloading pythonxy 2.7, the installation does not ask for which version I want.

I have to treat large data and I need much more memory per process (wich is actually limited to a few GB).

NB: I have a windows 10, 64 bites, 32 GB RAM.

Comment: It didn't ask which version to install because it is a 32-bit distribution of Python...

Comment: So it's impossible to get a 64-bit version with python 2.7?

Comment: Of Python(x,y) yes. You can download a 64-bit copy of Python and find/install all of the various modules you need though.

Comment: https://www.python.org/downloads/release

Comment: Here's a link to Python 2.7.5 64 bit MSI file. Note that it will start the download immediately because it's a direct link. https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.5/python-2.7.5.amd64.msi

Comment: It's easy to get Python 2.7 64 bit.....But it seems PythonXY comes only in 32 bit.....And if you install it, you cannot deselect Python 32 that comes with it.....And if you install Python 64 later, PythonXY doesn't work anymore.